# Convert comma separted with square brackets to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string

```
p, br, a[href,title], ul, li, em, strong
```

I want to convert this to array. I tried to use `explode` but it do not work as expected:

```
$tags = explode(',', $tags);
```

Above code output:

```
 array (
      0 => 'p',
      1 => ' br',
      2 => ' a[href',
      3 => 'title]',
      4 => ' ul',
      5 => ' li',
      6 => ' em',
      7 => ' strong'
 )
```

What should I do so I can get result like this:

```
array (
  0 => 'p',
  1 => ' br',
  2 => ' a' => array('href', 'title'),
  4 => ' ul',
  5 => ' li',
  6 => ' em',
  7 => ' strong'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that there always CSV will have schema comma and space, you can still use `explode()` with space added:

```
$tags = explode(', ', $tags);
```

Second option is using `trim()` on each value:

```
foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
    $tag = trim($tag);
}

unset($tag);
```

If you are reading your CSV from file the best solution will be using [`fgetcsv()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ar = explode(", ", $s);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++) {
    if (strpos($ar[$i], ",")) { //if is array formatted
        $begin = strpos($ar[$i], "[");
        $name = substr($ar[$i], 0, $begin);
        $content = substr(substr($ar[$i], $begin + 1), 0, -1);
        $newAr = explode(",", $content);
        unset($ar[$i]);
        $ar[$i][$name] = $newAr;
    }
}
$ar = array_values($ar);
```

Given `$s = "p, br, a[href,title], ul, li, em, strong";`, var_dump($ar) results in:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "p"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "br"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ul"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "li"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "em"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "strong"
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "href"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "title"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string actually consists of three RegEx patterns: tags with params (like `a[href,title]`),  tags without params and with a comma after it (like `br`), abd the last tag without params.

```
$patterns = [
    'tagWithoutParams' => '/(\w+)\,/',
    'lastTagWithoutParams' => '/\w+$/',
    'tagWithParams' => '/\w+\[\w+[,\w]*\]/',
];
$matches = [
    'tagWithoutParams' => [],
    'lastTagWithoutParams' => [],
    'tagWithParams' => [],
];

$string = 'p, br, a[href,title], img[src,style], ul, li, em, strong';

preg_match_all($patterns['tagWithoutParams'], $string, $matches['tagWithoutParams']);
preg_match_all($patterns['lastTagWithoutParams'], $string, $matches['lastTagWithoutParams']);
preg_match_all($patterns['tagWithParams'], $string, $matches['tagWithParams']);

$tags = array_merge(
    $matches['tagWithoutParams'][1],
    $matches['lastTagWithoutParams'][0],
    $matches['tagWithParams'][0]
);

/*
Another variant:
$patterns = ['tagWithoutParams'] => '/\w+\,/';
and then
array_walk($matches['tagWithoutParams'][0], function (&$value) {
    $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
});
and
$tags = array_merge(
    $matches['tagWithoutParams'][0],
    $matches['lastTagWithoutParams'][0],
    $matches['tagWithParams'][0]
);
*/

foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    if (strpos($tag, '[')) {
        $tagName = substr($tag, 0, strpos($tag, '['));
        $paramsString = substr($tag, strpos($tag, '[') + 1, (strpos($tag, ']') - strpos($tag, '[') - 1));
        $paramsArray = explode(',', $paramsString);
        $tags[$key] = [$tagName => $paramsArray];
    }
}

// test output
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tags);
```